# How to add css of a div when checkbox checked?

Tags: html, css

**The Code:**

```css
#menu-open:checked ~ .logoib {
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="logo" class="logoib"></div>

<input type="checkbox" id="menu-open">

<nav class="menu-list">
  <a href="#" class="firsta">Home</a>
  <a href="#">My Works</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</nav>

<label for="menu-open" class="modmenu logoib">
  <span></span>
</label>
```

I want to add some CSS of `#logo` when the checkbox of menu is checked.

Comment: In this context you can't.  You have to either settle for using javascript or place the input earlier in the DOM (before the `#logo` element)

Comment: yes, i was thinking... I will do this.. thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pure JS, JQuery or CSS.

Here is a pure JS solution. If you want to set it also on load, you could call `myFunction` when the DOM is ready.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var cb = document.getElementById('menu-open');
  var logo = document.getElementById('logo');

  if (cb.checked) {
    logo.setAttribute("class", "newClass");
  } else {
    logo.removeAttribute("class");
  }
}
```

```css
#menu-open:checked~.logoib {
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}
.newClass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo" class="logoib">Logo

</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="menu-open" onchange="myFunction()">

<nav class="menu-list">
  <a href="#" class="firsta">Home</a>
  <a href="#">My Works</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</nav>

<label for="menu-open" class="modmenu logoib">
  <span></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you LuLylulu, it works AWESOME :d  thank you all

Comment: glad I could help :)

Answer (score 4):

css cant affect anything before it, it can only affect stuff after the targeted element change like below

```css
#menu-open + #logo {
  color: #ccc;
  font-style: italic;
} 
#menu-open:checked + #logo {
  color: #f00;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="menu-open">
<div id="logo" class="logoib">
  my logo here
</div>

<nav class="menu-list">
  <a href="#" class="firsta">Home</a>
  <a href="#">My Works</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</nav>

<label for="menu-open" class="modmenu logoib">
  <span></span>
</label>
```

Comment: I tried to move up the input code, it works, but then css of menu-list doesn't